# Best way to run a python script multiple times through different directories? Using Windows

Tags: python, bash, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I have a python script that runs on input files in the same directory as the script using sys.argv:

```
    def main():
        input_1 = sys.argv[1]
        input_2 = sys.argv[2]
        output_file = sys.argv[3]
    ...
```

How can I get this script to run multiple times over each directory in a structure like this? I want it to be run over each data folder to grab type 1 and type 2 data to use in the script for x amount of times where x is number of data folders. Would I use bash, another python script, something else? I've never scripted for another script so anything helps. Thanks

```
 >folder
    >my_python_script.py
    >data
        >data_1
            >type_1
                data_type_1.txt
            >type_2
                data_type_1.txt
        >data_2
            >type_1
                data_type_1.txt
            >type_2
                data_type_1.txt
```

EDIT: The script also writes the two input files to an output file. This output file is created in the same directory as the script and the output name will change based on which directory the script is running on to not keep overwriting the same output file. So if it runs on 3 directories, there will be 3 different outputs.

Using Windows

I run the script in cmd like so:

```
python script.py 'input_1.txt' 'input_2.txt' 'out.txt'
```

Comment: xargs or parallel would probably be helpful. I'm not an expert enough in either to write an answer, though.

Comment: Are you going to run using bash or cmd or do you want something that runs on both? Please provide and example command line with all three (3) parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, I would use the `find` command to look for all *data_?* directories, then loop over them and call the python script:

```
SCRIPT=$PWD/my_python_script.py
for data_dir in $(find . -name 'data_?')
do
    cd $data_dir
    $SCRIPT
    cd - > /dev/null  # Returns to top dir
done
```

#### Discussion

- The script will loop over the directories
- For each dir, it will cd into it and run the script
- After the script ran, cd back to the top folder
- The `SCRIPT` variable points to the absolute path of the script, so it will be found regardless of current directory.

#### Update

I don't fully understand your question, so I am guessing that you want to pass data_1/data_type_1.txt as the first parameter and data_2/data_type_1.txt as second parameter:

```
SCRIPT=$PWD/my_python_script.py
for data_dir in $(find . -name 'data_?')
do
    cd $data_dir
    $SCRIPT data_1/data_type_1.txt data_2/data_type_2.txt
    cd - > /dev/null  # Returns to top dir
done
```

As for the third parameter, I cannot guess.

Comment: how can I pass the names/paths of the data.txt files to the python script? The python script takes in the names of the input files as arguments. I also edited the question to include handling of making unique output files per directory

Comment: The third parameter would be the output. I added how I run the script normally to the edit in the post (sorry for any confusion). The output file name should change based on which directory the script is working on. Say you run on directories a,b,c ... your output might be something like a_output.txt, b_output.txt, ...